# Solution exists ot this PDE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Hi I came across this PDE in solving some problem I was working on and seeing as I do not have that much experience in PDEs I was stumped when trying to demonstrate its existence. :
$$
\partial_t f_{j,k}(t,x) + \sum_{i=1}^d\mu_i(t,x)\partial_{x_i} f(t,x) + \sum_{i,j=1}^d\sigma_i(t,x)\sigma_j(t,x)\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j} f(t,x) = g(t,x).  
$$

Here $\mu_i,\sigma_i$ and $g$ are infinitely differentiable functions.  Alternatively, what are some conditions (not too stringent) which would guarantee the existence of a solution to such a PDE?

Comment: This is **the** prototype of a linear parabolic PDE. Once you have ellipticity on the coefficients of the second order term (which I assume you do), the existence in such a smooth setting is guaranteed. Of course you can weaken it down a lot, to so called parabolic-Hölder spaces. These results can be found in, say, Ladyzenskaya or Krylov

Comment: By eliplicticty you mean bounded away from 0?